# Windows 7 CMD.exe jumplist possible?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, jumplist

It seems CMD does not have it's own jumplist.Has someone created one already?
I would like to be able to pin script and command files to cmd.exe only.I can pin them separately with the */explorer* as the first line on target box but i would like all of them to be pinned to cmd.exe by default.Kind of like all folders are pinned to explorer.exe.I also made a rather bad looking mockup to make the question a little more clear:

[image]

Comment: Hey, add your voice to the suggestion for MS. Visit this `connect` issue and upvote: https://connect.microsoft.com/WindowsServerFeedback/feedback/details/561111/cmd-jumplist .

Comment: Thanks.I have a user in MS Connect so i was able to instantly add my upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this program... [JumplistExtender](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/05/19/jumplist-extender-adds-windows-7-jumplists-to-programs-which-don/) . It lets you create a jumplist on CMD which lets you have "pins" for your scripts. just add an item to CMD.exe through the admin and set it to send the keys to the application `/k c:\path\to\your\script.cmd` and it will work exactly like a pin on CMD.  :)

Comment: Wow.Looks like exactly what i want.I will check it out today an report back.Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Indeed this i exactly what i wanted.Thank you so much for the hint.
This i how it looks now.And i can even create custom subcategories :O
http://a.imageshack.us/img214/7601/customcmd.jpg

Comment: Wow! That's a lot of pinned script! lol ... glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Unsure about the direct answer, but I recommend that you look into [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) instead; it's a free application that allows you to script stuff for hot-keys and it also has a sorta "prompt" feature that's very handy. I use it all the time, and it's much quicker than skimming through fat icon lists.

For instance, to use a Launchy-like (www.launchy.net) feature i press Win+Space (yes, it's possible to override the Win key) to bring up my own prompt. I type in gwhatever to open a browser and google for "whatever". wabc to Wikipedia, etc. You could easily do the same with your commands (as in "cbp" for Backup Permissions, "cbt" for Boot Tracing, etc).

Eventually Explorer and most other stuff becomes redundant stuff "in the way". Start using AutoHotkey, and when you see the amount of time it saves you, you'll be hooked for life. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Unfortunately i rarely use any hotkeys(windows or program specific).I find it more intuitive to use mouse.

Speaking of the issue i did found this program that allows to create custom jumplist: http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/ .Unfortunately it pins all items to its own separate icon and not cmd.I will tinker with it a little more and if i can't do what i need i will make a reccommendation to the developer.

Comment: http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/9519/97951229.jpg

This is the best i could come up with.Made with 7Stacks: http://www.alastria.com/index.php?p=software-7s