# Can I pin a cmd/batch file to command prompt on the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts, command-line, pin

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to pin either a Shortcut or a Batch file to the new Windows 7 Taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/100249/how-to-pin-either-a-shortcut-or-a-batch-file-to-the-new-windows-7-taskbar)
>   [Windows 7 CMD.exe jumplist possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/137789/windows-7-cmd-exe-jumplist-possible)

Hey all, just wanted to ask quick if anyone knows how to do this. If not I'll post it on connect.microsoft.com as a suggestion.

With Explorer pinned to the taskbar you can pin folders to Explorer, so they are in the jumplist for the explorer shortcut.

I have a shortcut to CMD pinned to my taskbar and would like to be able to do the same concept, ... that is to be able to pin a bat/cmd file to the CMD shortcut, so in the CMD jumplist, I could have quick access to a couple batch files I use routinely.

Anyone know a way to do this? I tried just dragging the batch file to the CMD shortcut on the taskbar like how you do with folders and Explorer, but that did not work.

Comment: Dupe http://superuser.com/questions/100249/how-to-pin-either-a-shortcut-or-a-batch-file-to-the-new-windows-7-taskbar http://superuser.com/questions/137789/windows-7-cmd-exe-jumplist-possible

Comment: The first q (100249) I already saw, it doesn't answer my question. The second one (137789) is my question exactly. It did not come up though when I started typing my question in the list of possible relations, otherwise I would've just favorited that one, as I always look through the whole list of possible dupes first.