# How do I add tasks for cmd.exe in Start Menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows, start-menu

How do I add some custom tasks for cmd.exe in Start Menu?

[image: example for powershell]

Comment: Here you go: [How To Geek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30131/create-custom-windows-7-jumplists-for-apps-that-dont-have-one/).

[Creating your own jump lists](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-create-your-own-custom-jump-list)

Comment: This app allows create jump lists for itself not for the other apps (such as cmd.exe). But it seems that it is impossible anyway.

Comment: Check these answers out: [Solution 1](https://superuser.com/questions/100249/how-to-pin-either-a-shortcut-or-a-batch-file-to-the-new-windows-7-taskbar). [Solution 2](https://superuser.com/questions/137789/windows-7-cmd-exe-jumplist-possible)